# Pessimistic Lock doesn't work

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm developing an application with JPA2.1. I have the followed trouble.

I'm trying to lock an entity in this way :

```
Book book = em.find(Book.class, 12);
em.lock(book, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

but if try to access from another windows browser or client to entity with id=12 , the system doesn't thrown PessimisticLockException?

Where am I wrong?

Comment: How are you wrapping your browser code within a transaction?  Could it be your first transaction is released before the other browser attempts to obtain the lock?

Comment: can you explain better? I'm using Spring like application container and vaadin like UI framework

Comment: Pessimistic locks require an EntityManager be associated to a transaction, and as ben mentioned in an answer below, the lock is only held for the life of the transaction.  Look at how you are obtaining the em and how it is associated to a transaction and when it is rolledback/committed compared to when other threads might be obtaining their locks

Answer (score 2):

The lock will be effective during the lifetime of the **transaction** but certainly not across multiple request-response loop (unless you have configured your entity manager and transaction manager to manage long time transaction).

The transaction MUST be a short-time living object (for performance reasons).

Optimistic write-lock means that `book` will not be modified by any other thread between the `lock` instruction and the end of the transaction. But the book object itself may live longer of course.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in another window/browser you try the same thing: to acquire a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock.

The problem that you have, is that the lock is released when the method returns (as the transaction ends), meaning that when you open the second browser/window, there is no lock anymore.

You should probably explain us the problem/scenario that you want to try to solve/test.

For the **general** situation:

Another possible cause could be that your database table does not support row-level locking. For example in MySql only the InnoDB storage engine supports "SELECT * FOR UPDATE" (which the PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock is translated into).

Comment: Yes, from other window/browser i did the same thing (acquire a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) lock. I'm using Oracle 10g